# Another method of writing code

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I write code to JavaScript. I need to handle multiple keys when pressed. The result of such a code.

```
var key = event.keyCode;
if (key === 39 {
      //some code
    }

if (key === 40) {
      //some code
    }

if (key === 38) {
      //some code
    }

if (key === 13) {
     //some code
}
```

I do not like this method, if there is another beautiful way? in the style of object-oriented programming? Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: using a `switch` sentence

Comment: use switch, faster

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1337565/2401386) might help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript is not an object oriented language per se.

What you could do is make a mapped object.

```
const obj = {
    "39" : () => { //do this },
    "40" : () => { //do this },
    "38" : () => { //do this },
    "13" : () => { //do this }
}
```

Then, when your event code comes in... use `const whatever = obj[event.keyCode]();`

I also believe that some form of destructuring can make this even fancier, but I'd have to brush up on it.

Comment: Might want to check the return value before using unless you're absolutely sure only those 4 keys will be pressed.

Comment: than it is better to switch?

Comment: @Carcigenicate very true, you can check that with `obj.hasOwnProperty(event.keyCode) ` before running the function, otherwise if not, it will error out. Good catch.

Comment: @Nikitc "Better" is highly subjective. This is certainly a good use case for a switch, but this works too.

Comment: ^ this. Storing functions is overhead so a switch will have better performance, but it's not really a noticeable speed difference. You'll have to do some pretty heavy processing for it to show

Comment: How about old browsers?

Comment: what about older browsers? and unmapped codes is mentioned above. check that the property exists before calling the method.

Answer (score 4):

A [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp): The switch statement is used to perform different actions based on different conditions.

```
 switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 39:
            code block
            break;
        case 40:
            code block
            break;
        default:
            code block
    }
```

Comment: I do not like switch. is there another way?

Comment: You may see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307157/alternative-to-the-switch-statement but I think that switch statement is the most useful

Answer (score 0):

Probably could use a lot of work, but this is with key names and supports key combinations :

```
var keyboardEvents = {};
var keys           = {};

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){

    keys[ e.key.toLowerCase() ] = true;

    for(var s in keyboardEvents){
        var p = s.split('+').map(function(k){return k.toLowerCase()}); 
        var f = true;
        for(var i=0;i<p.length;i++) if(!keys[ p[i] ]) f = false;
        if(f) keyboardEvents[s](e);
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    delete keys[ e.key.toLowerCase() ];
});
```

and usage is like so :

```
keyboardEvents['control+c'] = function(e){ ... };
keyboardEvents['alt+c+b+k'] = function(e){ ... };
```